# Replacing jQuery 'on' function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have some legacy jQuery code that looks like the following:

```
$(document).on('replace', 'div', function (e, new_path, original_path) {
  // do stuff here
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how to move this code into an AngularJS consistent approach. The code above is running when index.html gets loaded. I'm trying to move initialization code into a directive. Currently, I'm calling the directive as shown here:

```
<body initialize-page>
  ... content goes here
</body>
```

My directive looks like the following:

```
.directive('initializePage', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (element) {
            console.log('initialization code goes here.');
        }
    };
})
```

However, I don't know what the AngularJS equivalent of 'on' is. I'd like to get away from using jQuery if at all possible.

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some more code. What you're doing on page initialization may be better handled by some other means than "page initialization".

Comment: Doesn't Angular internally use jQuery? You can't avoid loading the library anyway if I remember right.

Comment: Internally, it uses either jQuery (if already present on the page) or jqLite (a mostly compatible subset of jQuery). This question isn't about using jquery on the page--he wants to get rid of the use of it directly and do things the "angular way".

Comment: what is code within the handler intended to do? More detail needed to steer to an angular approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular includes a subset of jquery it calls [jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element).  The jqlite version of `.on` has these constraints:

```
on() - Does not support namespaces, selectors or eventData
```

So, we can use the Angular `on`, but slightly differently than you did in jQuery (namely without the selector).

A directive's link function's second parameter is the element the directive is applied to.  So, while we can't specify a selector in `on`, we can use `find` on the `element` parameter to get your div.  Then we can chain the `on` to that result.  This gives us  the following link function:

```
link: function (scope,element,attrs) { 
         element.find('div').on('replace',  function (event) {
            console.log("got event: ",event);
         });
      };
```

Here's a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DtMW5/2/) in which I used click instead of replace just because it's easier to show.